# q-io: how to read response.body JSON object using Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, httprequest, httpresponse

I need to make an http request from one server to another server.

The server that will handle this request will just return a JSON Array of objects:

```
app.get('/array', function (req, res) {
  console.log('GET request received!');
  var response_array = [
    {
      value: 1234
    },
    {
      value: 1234
    },
    {
      value: 55
    }
  ];

  res.send(response_array);
});
```

I am using `q-io` to send the http request to that GET method `/array` and obtain the array:

```
var _getArray = function(externalUrl) {
  var request = {
    method: "GET",
    url: externalUrl
  };

  return HTTP.request(request)
    .then(function(response) {
      // I need to return the Array inside the body (a Promise) to
      // iterate on it later
      return response.body.read(); // but .read() returns a Buffer
    });
}
```

Both servers work right, as the request is correctly sent and received from one to another, and also the response.

The **issue** I have is that I am not achieving to obtain the JSON Array - as `read()` returns a Buffer and just `response.body` doesn't return the Array (as the docs say, it returns  a representation of a readable stream)... how can I handle this properly to obtain the Array correctly **with Promises**?

Comment: I think you don't need to read(), just use `return response.body`

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz no, that doesn't return the Array, it returns the [body Object](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q-io#body) which as the docs say, it is **a representation of a readable stream, either for the content of
a request or a response. It is implemented as a Q-IO reader.**

Comment: You'll probably have to `.read().then(JSON.parse)`

Comment: @Bergi thank you, that was actually what I was looking for, but didn't realize I could put it that way! Post an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether it's working because you said it's a promise for a *buffer*, not a string. But maybe it gets casted just fine...

Comment: yeah, the docs about `read()` say so: **returns a promise for the entire body as a string or a buffer.**! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get a promise for the body content of the response, you can get a promise for the JSON payload from that by passing it through [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
return HTTP.request(request)
  .then(function(response) { return response.body.read() })
  .then(JSON.parse);
```

Answer (score 0):

from the docs, https://github.com/kriskowal/q-io#body

it seems that you have to use `forEach` to get all items

Comment: but forEach seems to use callbacks, I want to return a promise